# Implement Custom-Data-Attribute for Razor Syntax in MVC Core 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Below code is normal HTML Code for DropDown which has Custom Attribute

```
 <select class="form-control" data-singleselect id="division_cp">
                      <option value="select">Select</option>
                      <option value="cp">CP</option>
</select>
```

Am trying to implement same in Razor Syntax and I did too , but am not able/don't know to add Custom attribute, tried several way to add and I failed to add.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DivisionId, Model.DivisionList ?? new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control " , @id = "Division_List" })
```

Above Code is Razor Syntax please help me out to add Custom Attribute "data-singleselect" in MVC Core 6

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this work for other attributes in Razor, hopefully it may work in your case:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>
    model.DivisionId,
    Model.DivisionList ?? new List<SelectListItem>(),
    "--Select--",
    new
    {
        @data-singleselect="data-singleselect",
        @class = "form-control " , 
        @id = "Division_List"
    })
```

Doing the same thing for required and readonly works

```
@required="required",
@readonly="readonly"
```